# How can I get a similar "handmade feel" stroke in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

[image]

Hi ! How can I get this shape with Illustrator ? ( I refer to the house shape, both inner and outer shape).

I tried to use the Pencil tool, then I edited the stroke using "Roughen", but the result is not what I expected. The shape, the feel, the stroke that you can see on the pic is really what I would love. Should I use a tablet instead of the mouse?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Is there a way to imitate a pencil or pen in illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/is-there-a-way-to-imitate-a-pencil-or-pen-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 5):

To be *truly* effective, you need to do this manually...

- create the shape then add anchors and move them
- draw by hand and scan/trace.

I think the top option is generally quicker and easier, but takes some "fiddling" to get where you want.

[image]

I merely added anchor points to the shape's path. Converted those new anchors to smooth points and **moved the handles** a little.

To the best of my knowledge, none of the effects are going to be as subtle as your example.

---

Another option, although possibly more complex than necessary, would be to use an **Envelope Mesh**.

- Draw the shape and then select it
- Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make With Mesh` and enter a good number of columns/rows based upon the object....
  [image]
- Use the Direct Selection Tool to move handles and mesh anchors around...

[image]

---

A third option would be to use the **Warp Tool**

[image]

- Draw your shape
- Grab the Warp Tool
- Start pushing and pulling segments

[image]

<sub>Note, my shape *does* have Effect > Stylize > Rounded Corners applied to it, in all 3 examples.</sub>

Comment: You are a genious Scott ! Thanks a LOT ! I'm going to explore all those options and suggestions later today. I'm pretty sure those solutions will work like a charm ! Thanks again, I'll keep you posted about the results ! (happy happy happy)

Comment: Glad I could help.. the Warp tool is probably the best path to pursue -- at least it would be for me if I wanted more of a "happy accident" type of feel.

Comment: I succeded ! Thank you ! Rounded conners under Effects > Stilyze added an extra flavour to your amazing hints. Thank you a lot. Would you live to see the final result ?